# Php-ffmpeg “Unknown encoder libfaac” on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I am using laravel 4.2.

I am working on a project in that user can upload a video and I need to transcode it that it can be played over all kind of devices.

For transcoding I have added php-ffmpeg package from git hub in my project. According to the instructions I have downloaded ffmpeg package from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds and set the ffmpeg.exe's path into the environment variable Path.

Now, I tried code below to transcode an uploaded video :

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open($video_path);
$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
$format->setKiloBitrate(1000)
        ->setAudioChannels(2)
        ->setAudioKiloBitrate(256);
$video->save($format, public_path().$path.$save_filename);
```

But it gives error as below :

```
[ERROR] ffmpeg version N-70767-gd24af70 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
[ERROR]   built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
[ERROR]   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
[ERROR]   libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
[ERROR]   libavcodec     56. 28.100 / 56. 28.100
[ERROR]   libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
[ERROR]   libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
[ERROR]   libavfilter     5. 12.100 /  5. 12.100
[ERROR]   libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
[ERROR]   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
[ERROR]   libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'http://localhost/ohvideo-ftp/public/temp/5ZPlIuU1AIgz8RR4p0bs.mp4':
[ERROR]   Metadata:
[ERROR]     major_brand     : mp42
[ERROR]     minor_version   : 0
[ERROR]     compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
[ERROR]     creation_time   : 2013-11-09 00:29:52
[ERROR]   Duration: 00:00:30.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 417 kb/s
[ERROR]     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 381 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
[ERROR]     Metadata:
[ERROR]       creation_time   : 2013-11-09 00:29:52
[ERROR]       handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
[ERROR]       encoder         : AVC Coding
[ERROR]     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
[ERROR]     Metadata:
[ERROR]       creation_time   : 2013-11-09 00:29:52
[ERROR]       handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
[ERROR] Unknown encoder 'libfaac'
[ERROR] 
{"error":{"type":"FFMpeg\\Exception\\RuntimeException","message":"Encoding failed","file":"F:\\wamp\\www\\ohvideo-ftp\\vendor\\php-ffmpeg\\php-ffmpeg\\src\\FFMpeg\\Media\\Video.php","line":168}}
```

After searching alot, I found a link for the solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/512368/unknown-encoder-libx264-on-windows), with note that

> Zeranoe's ffmpeg does not contain libfaac support due to that encoder
>   requiring --enable-nonfree which would result in a non-redistributable
>   build.

I don't get the solution. Can anybody help me to overcome this?

### **Edit: (working code as below)**

I have created a `CustomVideo` class the same like class `FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264()` as below:

```
class CustomVideo extends FFMpeg\Format\Video\DefaultVideo
{
    /** @var boolean */
    private $bframesSupport = true;

    public function __construct($audioCodec = 'libmp3lame', $videoCodec = 'libx264')
    {
        $this
            ->setAudioCodec($audioCodec)
            ->setVideoCodec($videoCodec);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function supportBFrames()
    {
        return $this->bframesSupport;
    }

    /**
     * @param $support
     *
     * @return X264
     */
    public function setBFramesSupport($support)
    {
        $this->bframesSupport = $support;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getAvailableAudioCodecs()
    {
        return array('libmp3lame');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getAvailableVideoCodecs()
    {
        return array('libx264');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getPasses()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getModulus()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

and updated the code to transcode video as below:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open($video_path);
$format = new CustomVideo();
$format->setKiloBitrate(1000)
       ->setAudioChannels(2)
       ->setAudioKiloBitrate(256);

$video->save($format, public_path().$path.$save_filename);
```

It has solved the `Unknown encoder libfaac` error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The required library is not included due to licensing.

> **Zeranoe FFmpeg - Why dont the builds include FAAC, FDK-AAC, libaacplus**?
>
> These libraries are not compatible with the GPL license and cannot be
>   included without licensing the build as nonfree. A nonfree build
>   cannot be publicly distributed.

You have the following solutions:

1. Use another audio codec instead of AAC. There's a LAME MP3 encoder for example.
2. Compile your own version of FFmpeg adding all the libraries you want
   See [FFmpeg Compilation Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me try it.

Comment: How can I use another audio codec since I need to invoke the ffmpeg through the sample code as I have given in the question?? Regarding my own ffmpg compilation, the document is so much confusing. Is there any easy documentation where they have mentioned the configuration step by step?

Comment: To create a custom format extend the `Format\Video\X264` class and override the audio codec. [See the readme](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg).

Comment: I did it and the error has solved now but it loses the sound from the transcoded video. Please see my code updates in question.

Answer (score 15):

I just had the some problem, but solved it by defining a new audio-codec in the constructor. Instead of this line in the question...

```
$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
```

I used...

```
$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame', 'libx264');
```

Comment: thanks its working for me but it degrade my video quality too much. Does it causing by using this ?

Comment: I didn't notice any degradation, but I'm using it for mobile phone videos so the quality might not be good to start with.

Answer (score 1):

The [official recommendation](https://twitter.com/ffmpeg/status/782964711440588803) is to use the native FFmpeg AAC encoder or libfdk_aac instead:

```
$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('aac', 'libx264');
```